# Why doesn't the default array construction work in this setting?

Tags: java, arrays

Why doesn't the default array construction work in this setting? These are the errors I get:

"]" expected,
";" expected,
illegal start of type, identifier expected (each of them 8 times)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    ColoredWordsExperiment coloredWords;
    public ButtonHandler(ColoredWordsExperiment coloredWords) {
        this.coloredWords = coloredWords;
    }

    String colorWords[] = new String[8];
    colorWords[0] = "blue";
    colorWords[1] = "red";
    colorWords[2] = "purple";
    colorWords[3] = "yellow";
    colorWords[4] = "green";
    colorWords[5] = "pink";
    colorWords[6] = "orange";
    colorWords[7] = "grey";

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //If button "Matching" is clicked  
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Matching")) {
            coloredWords.label1.setText(colorWordGenerator(colorWords));
        }
    }

    public String colorWordGenerator(String colorWords[]) {
        Random generator = new Random();
        int i = generator.nextInt(7);
        return colorWords[i];
    }

}
```

However, if I put the array in a new, clean, class like this, it does work.

```
public class {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
         String colorWords[] = new String[8];
         colorWords[0] = "blue";
         colorWords[1] = "red";
         colorWords[2] = "purple";
         colorWords[3] = "yellow";
         colorWords[4] = "green";
         colorWords[5] = "pink";
         colorWords[6] = "orange";
         colorWords[7] = "grey";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class body contains method and variable definitions. The variable definitions may come with an initializer. However you can't put arbitrary statements into a class body. In other words you can't put your assignment statements into the class body - you'll need to put them into a method or the constructor.

In your second piece of code the assignments are all inside a method, so that why that one compiles fine.

In this particular case a better solution than putting the assignment statements into the constructor, would be to not assign to the individual indices of the array at all and instead use braces to initialize the array with values like this:

```
String colorWords[] = {"blue", ...};
```